# Bind a primitive to Laravel IoC container and resolve in a controller method

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm trying to resolve a primitive inside a `controller` method.

This is the register method of my Provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\InvalidCustomerController')
        ->needs('$customers')
        ->give(function () {
            return InvalidCustomer::latest()
                ->paginate(20);
        });
}
```

And this is the controller method I'm trying to resolve `$customers`:

```
public function index($customers)
{
    return view(
        'customer.invalid.index',
        compact('customers')
    );
}
```

`$customers` is not filled.

Everything will work if I resolve that on constructor.

What am I doing wrong?

ps: I'm using Laravel 5.2

Comment: have you tried type hinting it? `index(InvalidCustomer $customers)` & `->needs('InvalidCustomer')`

Comment: Then I would need to create InvalidCustomer interface?

Comment: not necessarily ... I don't think so

Comment: I think I can't typehint something that doesn't exists for a method argument. I will try.

Comment: Yes, I need to create something to typehint. But since I'm returning a Eloquent Collection I can't use a interface. (I guess)

Comment: any luck? post the updates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122534/discussion-between-alvaro-guimaraes-and-sherif).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you found a solution but to use a primitive in a controller, pass it through the __constructor of the controller class as so:

```
private $customers;
public function __construct($customers) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->customers = $customers;
}
```

This $customers variable can then be used elsewhere inside of the class.